# How to build SHTTPD on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, build, nmake

I tried building [SHTTPD](http://docs.huihoo.com/shttpd/) on Windows using the following command:

```
nmake msvc Makefile
```

All i get is a bunch of errors. What am I doing wrong?

> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. cl /MD /TC /nologo /DNDEBUG /Os standalone.c /link /out:shttpd.exe ws2_32.lib user32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib shttpd.lib standalone.c c:\users\samira\desktop\network\shttpd-1.42\src\compat_win32.h(46) : warning C4005: 'EWOULDBLOCK' : macro redefinition C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\errno.h(132) : see previous definition of 'EWOULDBLOCK' –

Comment: Please post the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

According to the site you link, you have to use the command

```
nmake win
```

to build on windows.

**Edit** From the site you linked:

> Download the source package. Extract
>   it, **go to src directory**. Run "make
>   unix" there ("nmake win" on Windows,
>   requires MSVC). That buillds a
>   library.

Have you invoked the command from the `src` directory?

Comment: C:\Users\Desktop\network\shttpd-1.42\src>nmake win

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.21022.08
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'win'
Stop.

Comment: @win-user: Maybe [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoose-users/browse_thread/thread/eadb2f2255f34c7c/3034e4b6f210345d?lnk=gst&q=nmake+win+does+not+work#3034e4b6f210345d) from the newsgroup will help.